# ASP.NET MVC 3 Html helper not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For some reason my Html helper is not recognized.

```
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@using System.Data
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Visits</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{  
            public string GetSiteVisits()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "SELECT numVisits FROM tblSiteVisits WHERE IPAddress='" + Request.UserHostAddress + "'",
                    new SqlConnection("Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"));

                sda.Fill(dt);

                string table = "<table><tr>";

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                       table += "<th>" + dc.ColumnName + "</th>";
                }

                table += "</tr>";

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    table += "<tr>";

                    foreach (Object o in dr.ItemArray)
                    {
                        table += "<td>" + o.ToString() + "</td>";   
                    }

                    table += "</tr>";
                }

                table += "</table>";

                return table;
            }
        }
        <div>
            @Html.Raw(GetSiteVisits())
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you performing model work in the view?

Comment: Why are you using MVC if you don't intend to follow the pattern?

Comment: Please learn the pattern before using it. This is not at all how it is meant to be used.

Comment: The point of SO is not to judge others code but to help fix it.  The question isn't bad and not worth downvoting.

Comment: @jfar: Exactly. Hypercritical comments and excessive downvoting discourages new users from posting their code. @48klocs comment was enough to get the point across.

Answer (score 5):

The way to write Html helpers is 
In the helper return the string.

```
 <html>
      <body>
          <div>
              @GetSiteVisits()
         </div>    
      </body>
  </html>
  @helper GetSiteVisits()
  {
        @Html.Raw("hello");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your namespace:

```
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@using System.Data
@using Mine.MyHtmlHelper.MyNameSpace // Here!!
```

Answer (score 2):

The function GetSiteVisits() needs to be in your controller, not the view. The data that the method generates (reads from the database) then goes into a view model which gets passed to the view. In rough psuedo code it should be something like this:

Model

```
public class IPVisits
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public int NumVisits { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class SiteVisitsViewModel
{
    public List<IPVists> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
// SiteVisits method only
public ActionResult SiteVisits(string id)
{
    // Get the data for the UserHostAddress
    list = Repository.GetTheDataInListForm(id);
    return View(list);
}
```

View

```
foreach( var d in Model.Visits)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@d.IPAddress</td>
        <td>@d.NumVisits</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this is in your web.config file (probably in the root as well as in ~/Views folder):

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug = "true" targetFramework = "4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly = "System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly = "System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly = "System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly = "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly = "System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

The important line is really just `System.Web.Mvc, ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is asp.net MVC, MVC means Model (business logic), View(presentation layer, or what client see), and controller, which operates with requests. Why you use Model in View. It will be correct, to make operation with sql in a Model class, invoke it in controller, and send to View by a ViewData. There is no reason to use asp.net MVC in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

In your Views directory there should be a Web.config. You just need to add the namespace to your helper